# Failing To Display Only Available Items in View

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm, viewmodel

I am a C++ Developer and have recently shifted to C#. I am developing a WPF app where I need to generate Ui components like buttons, textbox etc dynamically. This is how i have done till now.

**XAML Class:**

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource booltovisibility}}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <convert:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booltovisibility"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="115" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ChannelName}" Height="25" Width="120" Name="VoltageLabel" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding VoltageText}" Height="25" Width="65" Name="VoltageBox" Margin="0,0,80,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Set" CommandParameter="{Binding VoltageText}" Command="{Binding VoltageCommand}" Height="25" Width="65" Name="VoltageSetbtn" Margin="80,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding CurrentText}"  Height="25" Width="40" Name="CurrentLabel" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="3" Content="On"  Height="25" Width="30" Name="VoltageToggleBtn" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>

<Button Content="Bavaria" Name="BavariaBtn" Click="BavariaBtn_Click" />
```

**ViewModel Class:**

```
public List<VoltageBoardChannel> channelList = null;       

    public List<VoltageBoardChannel> bavaria2Channels = new List<VoltageBoardChannel>
    {
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__MAIN", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__IO__AUD", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__CODEC__AUD", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__DAL__AUD", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__DPD__AUD", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__PLL__AUD", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },        
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand }
    };

    private ICommand m_voltageCommand;        

    public List<VoltageBoardChannel> bavaria1Channels = new List<VoltageBoardChannel>
    {
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand }
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__MAIN", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__IO", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__CODEC", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__LDO", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__AMP", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand }             
    };            

    public VoltageViewModel()
    {
        channelList = new List<VoltageBoardChannel>(0);
        channelList = bavaria1Channels;            
        m_voltageCommand = new DelegateVoltageCommand(x => SetCommandExecute(x));
    }

    public List<VoltageBoardChannel> VoltageChannelList
    {
        get 
        { 
            return channelList; 
        }

        set
        { 
            channelList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChannelList");
        }
    }        

    public void SetCommandExecute(object voltageText)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(voltageText);
    }
```

**Model Class:**

```
private string mChannelName;
    public string ChannelName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private bool mIsAvailable;
    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string voltageText = string.Empty;
    public string VoltageText
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string currentText = "0 V";
    public string CurrentText
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public ICommand VoltageCommand { get; set; }
```

**XAml.cs:**

```
 VoltageViewModel mVoltageViewModel = new VoltageViewModel();

    public VoltageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = mVoltageViewModel;

        OnChildAdd();
    }
public void OnChildAdd() //Constructor
    {   
        VoltageViewModel mVoltageViewModel = new VoltageViewModel();         
        foreach (VoltageBoardChannel mVoltageChannelViewModel in mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList)
        {
            VoltageChannelView mVoltageChannelView = new VoltageChannelView();
            mVoltageChannelView.Margin = new Thickness(2);
            mVoltageChannelView.ChannelInfo = mVoltageChannelViewModel;
            // Some Code
        }
    }
```

Here It displays all the channels of Bavaria 1 even the one's where `available = false`. Thus when its false, it displays the textbox, button, label and togglebutton. The Channelname is "". I wanna to achieve the following:

I have 2 channels here, **bavaria 1 and bavaria 2.** On startup bavaria1 is already displayed. Here I want to check for available channels and add only those to my view on startup i.e. `available = true` should be displayed and when `available = false`, the corresponding element should not be displayed. Currently even `available = false` gets displayed with button, textbox, togglebutton except label(Channelname will be ""). How can i achieve that?

Comment: Could you show your complete view XAML? The XAML above seems only to be the code for a single element, not for the surrounding view, where the problem seems to be.

Comment: channelList = new List<VoltageBoardChannel>(0);
channelList = bavaria1Channels;          

This is some strange code. You don't need to 'new' a list you'll assign something completely different too. Thats 'sloppy' memory management.

Comment: @Akku: updated the xaml. Check

Comment: I don't know if the Grid's resource of the boolToVisibilityConverter conflicts with the static one. I would just use the static one and define that in the App.xaml file. If that doesn't fix it, I wonder how the Grid should know which it's model object is. Shouldn't you set the Grid's DataContext to the current channel somewhere? I can't see this in the code anyways, and the grid is also not named, so make sure (debugger) that the DataContext is set correctly. Also I agree to CodingBarfield that you build up your code in a pretty strange way, which might be the reason we didn't find a fix yet.

Comment: @Akku: Yes I am getting the error because of Grid.Resources. This voltage class is a user control, not a window. Any other way to get it done? Plus I have updated the xaml.cs class :) How can I get this availability done?

Comment: @Akku: I got it. Using `UserControl.Resources` I set the converter and its working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide an element in XAML using a boolean binding, you need to convert it, since the Visibility property of elements is not a boolean field.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding VoltageChannelList}">
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booltovisibility"/>
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsAvailable,
                     Converter={StaticResource booltovisibility}}">
     <!-- controls -->
  </Grid>
</ListBox>
```

Using the default [BooleanToVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) converter.

---

With that said, you should probably change VoltageChannelList to an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) so when you insert or remove items, the change is reflected to your view.

Also note that when you use autoproperties you don't create a backing field

```
private bool mIsAvailable; // this is not used by the property below
public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
```

when using this code mIsAvailable is never returned from a call to IsAvailable, since it creates its own backing field.

Comment: no need to define a BooleanToVisibilityConverter, you can use the default implementation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Patrick: Hey bro it throws an exception on my xaml file. `'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.'` I have updated the xaml. Check if its right?

Comment: Corrected the problem :) Thanks for helping mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like creating a property like this:

```
List<VoltageChannel> AvailableChannels {
  get
  {
     var returned = new List<VoltageChannel>();
     foreach (VoltageChannel vc in VoltageChannelList)
     {
        if (vc.IsAvailable)
          returned.add(vc);
     }
     return vc;
  }
}
```

Then, bind your view to this property, maybe with an ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="_itemsControl"  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableChannels}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate><WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      ... (your XAML to show the channels) ...
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

(Didn't test your code)